# How to declare the module type of an react component for flowtype, without breaking the formatter?

Tags: javascript, types, reactjs, formatter, flowtype

I defined a react component and use flow to check it:

```
/** @flow */
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var React = require('react');

var Hello = React.createClass({
    propTypes: {
        content: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <section>hello</section>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Hello;
```

But flow reports an error:

```
/Users/twer/workspace/yyy/a.js:16:16,20: ReactElement
Missing annotation
```

Because flow requires an module having type explicitly: http://flowtype.org/docs/type-annotations.html#module-boundaries

And for an react component, I need to declare the type on the `render` method, so I have to fix it like this:

```
render: function(): ?ReactElement {
    return (
        <section>hello</section>
    );
}
```

The problem is, it will break the formatter of my IDEA (because of the `?` of `?ReactElement`)

Is there any other place to put the `?ReactElement`?

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you figured something out by now, but note that the `?` is optional.

```
render: function(): React.Element {
   // ...
}
```